# "They each tells a story."

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, adjuncts

Which one is correct:

> 1. They each **tells** a story.

or

> 2. They each **tell** a story.

Does "each" change the plural form of the verb? Thanks.

Comment: Similar question from English.SE: ['Each' with plural or singular verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/each-with-plural-or-singular-verb)

Comment: Your #1 version is ungrammatical; your #2 version is fine. Your use of the word "each" in your examples does not affect subject-verb agreement (which should be plural in number). -- The word "each" that is used in both of your examples is functioning as a *quantificational adjunct* (*CGEL*'s terminology), and is semantically associated with the subject (the subject is "they"). Consider: *"They **each** would have to tell a story", "They would **each** have to tell a story"*. -- For more info there's *CGEL* pages 102 [36], 413 [13], 428 [7].

Comment: @F.E. Are there posts or links about how to choose a grammar book? reviews and comparison between grammar books?

Comment: It depends on your needs. For instance, for my needs, I need a solid grammar reference to defend myself from pedants, and to defend my own prose from pedantic editors. The 2002 *CGEL* is an 1,800 page reference grammar that is rather concise (equivalent to 4,000 pages of a textbook); it is a good place to begin when researching grammar issues. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) As for people who want a more typical grammar textbook (300-500 pages), er, that's going to be mostly pot-luck. I guess it depends on whether you are a linguistics student, or a writer, or etc. You might want to use Amazon's "look-inside" feature to judge the books, and read the buyers' reviews. -- As for posts on grammar books, I think there are some existing ones around, either on meta-ELL or meta-EL&U.

Comment: I would like to know books at different levels. How about comparing Quirk et al's comprehensive grammar book to CGEL? @F.E.

Comment: That one is rather long in the tooth. 1985 Quirk et al. is 30 years old now, and when it was written, it hedged quite a bit, and it was influenced a lot with the prevailing traditional grammar of its day--so it is a mix of both, traditional grammar and modern grammar; though we tend to consider it the first main modern grammar reference. My personal opinion is that its framework is too complicated and requires too much memorization, though its examples and explanations are still invaluable. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) If you're going to buy a reference grammar, you might as well get the 2002 *CGEL* by Huddleston and Pullum (et al.). But their book is around $250 USA, so it's expensive, while the older 1985 book is a little over $100. Of course, if you have the money, I'd recommend getting both, and read the 2002 H&P book starting with its first page. :)

Comment: There's also the 2005 textbook by Huddleston and Pullum, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, which is around $30. But it is a typical textbook--though, it is good, but dry in info. It too is necessary for one's grammarian bookshelf because it does have some info that is missing in the 2002 *CGEL*.

Answer (score 13):

When *each* is used as a *pronoun*, it is always singular:

> **Each** of my children **tells** a story.

However, here, it looks like *each* is an *adverb* that modifies *tell*:

> **They** each **tell** a story.
>
> **They tell** one story each.

This makes it clear that each person tells a story. Without *each*, maybe they are telling one story as a group. Consider the difference between the two sentences:

> The students line up on the stage, and they sing a song.
>
> The students line up on the stage, and they **each** sing a song.

In the first case, we get one song. In the second case, we get many songs (one song per student).

---

Some people might argue that this use of *each* is grammatically an *adjective* modifying *they*, indicating that each member of the subject ("they") should be considered separately. I'm not sure if an adjective can supply that kind of semantic meaning to a sentence, though. Consider the word *together*, when used an adverb:

> They sing a song together.

It is very clear to me that *together* does not modify *they* as an adjective; it modifies *sing* as an adverb. It makes sense to me that the opposite sentence uses *each* an adverb as well. However, I might be wrong and welcome clarification from a more knowledgeable grammarian.